# LAContext.biometryType always returns LABiometryTypeTouchID

Tags: ios, objective-c, face-id

I am already using TouchID in my project, now i am trying to use FaceId for authentication and i am using the following code.

```html
LAContext *myContext = [[LAContext alloc] init];
NSError *authError = nil;
    if (![myContext canEvaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics error:&authError])
    {
        NSLog(@"0001 , EVT, %@, %@, %@",[[self class] description], NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), [authError localizedDescription]);
        return NO;
    }
    
    if (@available(iOS 11.0, *))
    {
        if (myContext.biometryType == LABiometryTypeFaceID)
        {
            NSLog(@"0002 , EVT, %@, %@, FaceID Suppoted Device",[[self class] description],NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
        }

  if (myContext.biometryType == LABiometryTypeTouchID)
        {
            NSLog(@"0002 , EVT, %@, %@, Touched Suppoted Device",[[self class] description],NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
        }
    }
```

myContext.biometryType always returns LABiometryTypeTouchID(1), but the device iam using is iPad 11 inch with iOS 12.1.4 (has only faceid no touchid).

But if i run the following evaluatePolicy: faceid UI is prompted. But even after that i get myContext.biometryType returns LABiometryTypeTouchID(1)
, 
any idea why this returns LABiometryTypeTouchID(1) rather than LABiometryTypeFaceID (2)?

```html
[myContext evaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics
                  localizedReason:myLocalizedReasonString
                            reply:
```

NOTE - This works perfectly on iPhoneX with iOS 12.1.4 but dosent work in iPad 11 inch iOS 12.1.4 STRANGE...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the following answer from Apple.

It seems that you’ve built your app against iOS 11.x SDK. Face ID functionality was disabled for iPads prior to iOS 12, that’s why it’s being recognized as Touch ID.

Please make sure you build the app using an up to date Xcode, that is against iOS 12.x SDK